# Multivariate inequality of floor function

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities, convex-analysis

Define $$f(x,a) := (2x-a)\lfloor\frac{x}{a}\rfloor-a\lfloor\frac{x}{a}\rfloor^2.$$
It seems that $$f(x,a)+f(x,b)\geq 2f(x,c),\forall a,b \in [1,x],a+b=2c.$$

I have written a program that has checked this equality for $x \leq 1000$

however, I have struggled with this inequality for many days and found no research papers involving multivariate inequality of floor function ( only basic properties )

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

For $1 \le a \le x$ is
$$
f(x, a) = x \cdot g\left( \frac a x\right)
$$
where $g$ is defined as
$$
 g(u) = (2-u) \left\lfloor \frac 1u \right\rfloor - u \left\lfloor \frac 1u \right\rfloor ^2
$$
for $0 < u \le 1$. It is a straightforward calculation to show that $g$ is *convex* (it is continuous, piecewise linear, with non-decreasing slope).

The desired inequality is an immediate consequence of that convexity.

Comment: sorry I don't know how to prove g is convex, does it has second derivative?

Comment: @HaoHuang: As I said: The function is continuous, piecewise linear, with non-decreasing slope. Or to put it differently: The function is continuous, and differentiable everywhere except at the points $u=1/n$, and the derivative is non-decreasing. That is sufficient to prove convexity.